# Comparing list values against dict values

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like

```
myList = ['county name', 'state name', 'name of county seat'],
          ['county name', 'state name', 'name of county seat']
```

and a dict with state names as keys and state abbreviations as values.

```
state_names = {'alabama': 'AL', ...}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through myList and return the abbreviation of the matching state.

I tried this:

```
for entry in myList:
    state_name = entry[1].lower()
    for key in state_lookup.stateNames:
        if state_name == key:
            return state_lookup.stateNames[key]
```

Which doesn't work for reasons that I'm sure are obvious to someone else.

Comment: Can you tell us what your dict looks like?

Answer (score 3):

That isn't generally the structure you'd want to have for that sort of data, you should have some sort of nested structure. So the correct answer involves changing where you got that data from to give you data in that way (a list of tuples say).

But if that's what you have, you'd need the [grouper recipe from the itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) or to use yourdata[1::3] to slice out your state names which you can then write a list comprehension to look up.

Comment: a list or a set of tuples in the form `{(state, abbr)}` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: What is the structure I should be using? A nested list? I can't use a dict because the values in the list are not unique.

Comment: A nested list or a list of tuples, yes.

Comment: Probably should only use a list of tuples if the order is important and/or there aren't duplicates. Otherwise use a set of tuples.

Comment: In the format list = `[['county name', ['state name', 'name of county seat'], ...]?`

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name. Use this format: `[('county name', 'state name', 'county seat'), ...]` or `[['county name', 'state name', 'county seat'], ...]` or `{('county name', 'state name', 'county seat'), ...}` depending on the nature of the data.

Comment: OK so same format but turn each list item into a tuple?

Comment: If each "item" (i.e., each tuple) isn't going to change, yes, use a tuple (because they're immutable). If they change, use nested list or a dict. No, the middle one has nested lists. The format in the question does not have nested lists: `myList = ['county name', 'state name', 'name of county seat', 'county name', 'state name', 'name of county seat']`

Comment: Ok, now it's probably closer to what you want, though I think you'd still be better off using tuples, but it can be argued either way.

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed a bracket when entering my OP. It is in the format of `mylist = [['', '', ''], ['', '', '']...]`

Comment: I appreciate the tuple education but I still don't understand how to iterate through the list and find the matching value in the dict...

Comment: I realize that but before that can be addressed the data needs to be in a good format. Now it's doable. :) Looks like others are on their way to help you get there.

Answer (score 2):

You can slice your list using a stride of 3

Using `get()` lets you use a default value if the key is not found. In this case I've used `key` as the default value.

```
[state_lookup.stateNames.get(key.lower(), key) for key in myList[1::3]]
```

You may prefer to just skip missing keys

```
state_names  = state_lookup.stateNames
[state_names[key.lower()] for key in myList[1::3] if key.lower() in state_names]
```

It would simplify the code a little to group the triples into tuples in the first place - eg.

```
myList = [('county name', 'state name', 'name of county seat'),
          ('county name', 'state name', 'name of county seat'),
          ]
```

Then you might get something like

```
[state_lookup.stateNames.get(key[1].lower(), key) for key in myList]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
abbrevs = [state_lookup.stateNames.get(name.lower(), None) 
           for i, name in enumerate(my_list) if i % 3 == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using existing implementation

Your current code sample does not work because it will always return ONLY the abbreviation of the first state in `myList`.

Example:

```
myList = [['Montgomery', 'Ohio', 'Dayton'], ['Fayette', 'Kentucky', 'Lexington']]

for entry in myList:
    #1st iteration, entry = ['Montgomery', 'Ohio', 'Dayton']
    state_name = entry[1].lower()
    #1st iteration, state_name = 'ohio'
    for key in state_lookup.stateNames: 
    #not sure what state_lookup.stateNames is doing here...?
        if state_name == key:
        #loop will iterate until key gets to 'ohio' entry
            return state_lookup.stateNames[key]
            #'OH' abbreviation returned assuming that 
            #state_lookup.stateNames is a dict
```

You might find it useful to do this with a generator:

```
def state_abbr_from_CoStSeats(co_st_seats, state_lookup_dict):
    for co_st_seat in co_st_seats:
        yield state_lookup_dict[lower(co_st_seat)]
        #using yield instead of return creates a generator
```

Now you can get a list of abbreviations from your generator:

```
my_abbr_list = list(def state_abbr_from_CoStSeats(myList, state_lookup))
```

Alternatively, you could write a function that gets the abbreviation from the list item:

```
def state_abbr_from_CoStSeat(co_st_seat, state_lookup):
    return state_lookup[lower(co_st_seat[1])]
```

Then make a list of the abbreviations:

```
my_abbr_list =[state_abbr_from_CoStSeat(item, state_lookup) for item in myList]
```

---

### Using alternative implementation

Since the county name, state name, and name of county seat presumably don't change very often, I suggest abandoning your nested lists and use `collections.namedtuple` instead.

Example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
CoStSeat = namedtuple('CoStSeat','county state seat')
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
item = CoStSeat(state = 'Kentucky', county = 'Fayette', seat = 'Lexington')
```

And this:

```
assert item['state'] == 'Kentucky'
```

Populate `myList` maybe like this:

```
myList = []
iterable_items = <---some kind of iterable input-->
#the iterable input can be something like your nested lists or nested tuples 
#or even some kind of an input file
#
#this will work as long as your iterable_items object is in the form:
#    [[county, state, seat], ...] or 
#    [(county, state, seat], ...] or
#    {(county, state, seat], ...} 
for item in iterable_items: 
    myList.append(CoStSeat(*item))
```

And now you can do stuff like this:

```
states_iterable = (lower(item['state']) for item in myList)
#produces a generator that spits out the lowercase states
```

If you don't want to used `namedtuple` you can just do it like this:

```
states_iterable = (lower(item[1]) for item in myList) 
#this is assuming 1 is the address of the state name
```

This produces a generator that can be walked over in a `for` statement, or using `next()` like `next(states_iterable)` (until you reach the end).

So now you can just walk over your dictionary using your generator:

```
myAbbrList = []
for state in states_iterable:
    myAbbrList.append(states_dict[state])
```

If you want, you can do it ALL of this in one line:

```
my_abbr_list = [states_dict[lower(item[1]) for item in myList]
```

Or if you're using `namedtuple`:

```
my_abbr_list = [states_dict[lower(item['state']) for item in myList]
```